# BIND9 : can't find domain.tld: No answer

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

My Bind9 server answers "No answer" to any query :

```
ychaouche@ychaouche-PC 12:11:02 ~ $ nslookup google.com 10.10.10.7
Server:         10.10.10.7
Address:        10.10.10.7#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find google.com: No answer

ychaouche@ychaouche-PC 12:11:07 ~ $ nslookup facebook.com 10.10.10.7
Server:         10.10.10.7
Address:        10.10.10.7#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find facebook.com: No answer

ychaouche@ychaouche-PC 12:11:11 ~ $ nslookup twitter.com 10.10.10.7
Server:         10.10.10.7
Address:        10.10.10.7#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find twitter.com: No answer

ychaouche@ychaouche-PC 12:11:18 ~ $
```

Here's how it's configured.

```
root@dns2-sec 11:45:29 ~ # named-checkconf -p
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        listen-on-v6 {
                "any";
        };
        allow-query-cache {
                "any";
        };
        allow-recursion {
                "localnets";
                "localhost";
        };
        auth-nxdomain no;
        dnssec-validation auto;
        recursion yes;
        allow-query {
                "any";
        };
        allow-transfer {
                10.10.10.4/32;
        };
        also-notify {
        };
};
acl "ournets" {
        "localnets";
        192.168.200.0/24;
        192.168.201.0/24;
        192.168.202.0/24;
        192.168.203.0/24;
        192.168.204.0/24;
        192.168.205.0/24;
        192.168.206.0/24;
        192.168.207.0/24;
        192.168.208.0/24;
        192.168.209.0/24;
        192.168.100.0/24;
        192.168.101.0/24;
        192.168.102.0/24;
        192.168.103.0/24;
        192.168.104.0/24;
        192.168.105.0/24;
        192.168.106.0/24;
        192.168.107.0/24;
        192.168.108.0/24;
        192.168.109.0/24;
};
logging {
        channel "main_log" {
                file "/var/log/named/main.log" versions 3 size 2097152;
                severity info;
                print-time yes;
                print-severity yes;
                print-category yes;
        };
        category "default" {
                "main_log";
        };
        category "lame-servers" {
                "null";
        };
};
zone "algerian-radio.dz" {
        type slave;
        file "/etc/bind/slave/algerian-radio.dz.db";
        masters {
                10.10.10.4 ;
        };
};
zone "eprs.dz" {
        type slave;
        file "/etc/bind/slave/eprs.dz.db";
        masters {
                192.168.100.11 ;
        };
};
zone "10.10.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type slave;
        file "/etc/bind/slave/10.10.10.in-addr.arpa.db";
        masters {
                10.10.10.4 ;
        };
};
zone "1.201.197.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type slave;
        file "/etc/bind/slave/1.201.197.in-addr.arpa.db";
        masters {
                10.10.10.4 ;
        };
};
zone "10.16.172.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type slave;
        file "/etc/bind/slave/10.16.172.in-addr.arpa.db";
        masters {
                10.10.10.4 ;
        };
};
zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "/etc/bind/db.root";
};
zone "localhost" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};
zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.127";
};
zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.0";
};
zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.255";
};
root@dns2-sec 12:09:00 ~ #
```

**EDIT** : seems to work fine with dig though, problem may come from nslookup ?

```
ychaouche@ychaouche-PC 12:21:13 ~ $ dig @10.10.10.7 twitter.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.7-Ubuntu <<>> @10.10.10.7 twitter.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29371
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;twitter.com.                   IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
twitter.com.            84784   IN      NS      ns1.p34.dynect.net.
twitter.com.            84784   IN      NS      ns2.p34.dynect.net.
twitter.com.            84784   IN      NS      ns4.p34.dynect.net.
twitter.com.            84784   IN      NS      ns3.p34.dynect.net.

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.10.10.7#53(10.10.10.7)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 07 12:23:21 CET 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 126

ychaouche@ychaouche-PC 12:23:21 ~ $ nslookup  twitter.com 10.10.10.7
Server:         10.10.10.7
Address:        10.10.10.7#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find twitter.com: No answer

ychaouche@ychaouche-PC 12:23:42 ~ $
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with allow-recursion, I put back ournets instead and it went fine.

It seems nslookup only works if recursion is available.

Comment: Since what you're doing with nslookup is asking the server to do recursive lookups (unless the domain is yours), that's not surprising.. you can limit who can recurse with ACLs if it worries you...